# Get image in CSS and Playframework 2

Tags: css, playframework, playframework-2.1

Here is what I try to do:

*HTML/CSS* code:

```
<div style="display: block; background-image: url(@routes.Assets.at("/assets/images/favicon.png")));">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

The `favicon.png` file is located under `public/images` directory of *Play Framework*.

The problem is that this image never displays. 
Can you help me on this issue? How should I refer to this image from *CSS* and *Play Framework*? I tried many modifications to this, but without any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it should be like this

`background-image: url('@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")')`